# Log4j2 DirectWriteRolloverStrategy stuck at 100th log file

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I have the following log4j config

```
<RollingFile name="ROLLING_FILE">
        <FilePattern>logs/mylog.%010i.log.gz</FilePattern>
        <DirectWriteRolloverStrategy maxFiles="50"/>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 KB"/>
        </Policies>
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p %c [%t] (..%-C{3}) %x | %m%n</Pattern>
            <Header>${sys:log4j.mylog.name} ${sys:log4j.mylog.version} build-${sys:log4j.mylog.build.number}%n</Header>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Append>true</Append>
    </RollingFile>
```

and then I'm just logging infinitely

```
  for (; ; ) {
     log.error("errorrrrr");
  }
```

and it gets stuck at

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 test test 166 Mar  2 13:04 mylog.0000000098.log.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 test test 167 Mar  2 13:04 mylog.0000000099.log.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 test test   0 Mar  2 13:04 mylog.0000000100.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 test test 165 Mar  2 13:04 mylog.0000000100.log.gz
```

and it does not pass 100th file.

When I do not use the padding it works perfectly fine

```
             <FilePattern>logs/mylog.%i.log.gz</FilePattern>
```

So looks like a bug?

EDIT: To give some more context - I'm trying to find a configuration which gives me:

- easy grepping in a sorted order like

  ```
   zgrep "something" mylog.*
  ```
- total log file limit - I'm not able to use date-time patterns as there you get the limit per the date-time but i need a total one
- bonus would be for the most recent logs to be always in mylog.log ... and I'm wondering why it does not do it like that actually? ... at least a sym link could be provided for *nix systems

EDIT2: Seems like a bug in log4j 2.17.2 as with 2.20.0 it works as expected.

Comment: `maxFiles="50"` ????? 50 ???

Comment: Isn't it wasteful to have a 10-digit counter? Even if you produced 1 log file every second, it would still take you 317 years to get to the 9999999999th log file.

Comment: Guys, how is this related? In production I'm using <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50 MB"/> with maxFiles=50 ... the padding can be less of course - it is to illustrate the problem

Comment: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html, `maxFiles`,`The maximum number of files to allow in the time period matching the file pattern. If the number of files is exceeded the oldest file will be deleted. If specified, the value must be greater than 1. If the value is less than zero or omitted then the number of files will not be limited.`

Comment: Can you give more detail about what you mean by "it gets stuck at 100"? What happens after that? Does your app continue running but no logs are produced? Does your app hang and not return from a log call? By the way, I'm not sure what problem @life888888 is referring to either.

Comment: (1) if I config maxFiles="10", I will get `mylog.0000000001.log.gz,mylog.0000000002.log.gz,,...,mylog.0000000009.log.gz', **mylog.0000000010.log.gz**. (2) Why would I expect 100 log files to rotate when I set maxFiles to 10 only ? |(3) When I am testing the program, if I just use **while loop**, the log file will not be listed in the file explorer, because there is no chance. But when I add **thread sleep** in **while loop** , the file explorer will be able to list the log file.

Comment: @life888888 if you have maxFiles="10" and then you have reached a total of ten files mylog0001, ... mylog0010, then the next file will be created as mylog0011 and mylog0001 will be deleted. Then there will be mylog0012 and mylog0002 will be deleted. Thus, there will always be just 10 files, but the integer in the name will continue to go up forever.

Comment: @Klitos Kyriacou, log4j-core, log4j-api, 2.20.0, RollingFile, My Log file only `mylog.0000000001.log.gz,mylog.0000000002.log.gz,,...,mylog.0000000009.log.gz', mylog.0000000010.log.gz. No 0011 or 0012....

Comment: I tried reproducing your issue, but it's working as expected. The file names continue to be incremented, it's still running and the files have numbers in the hundreds of thousands.

Comment: I'm using 2.17.2 and it is 100% reproducible. @KlitosKyriacou which version are you using?

Comment: @life888888 there is no any time period matching the filename pattern - it is only %010i so the citation is not relevant.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou just tried with 2.20.0 and it works .. it was fixed obviously, thanks